# Does midpoint-convexity at a point imply midpoint-convexity at other points?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

This question is a follow-up of this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740970/does-midpoint-convexity-at-a-point-imply-midpoint-convexity-at-a-larger-point).

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function satisfying $f(0)=0$.

Suppose that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and that $f$ is strictly convex in some neighbourhood of $0$.

---

Given $c \in \mathbb R$, we say that $f$ is midpoint-convex **at the point $c$** if

$$
f((x+y)/2) \le (f(x) + f(y))/2,
$$
whenever $(x+y)/2=c$, $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

> **Question:** Let $r<s<0$, and suppose that $f$ is midpoint-convex at $r$. Is $f$ midpoint-convex at $s$?

In the example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3740984/104576) (essentially $(f(x)=-x^3$) $f$ is concave after its global minimum point, while here I assume that there is a convex neighbourhood.

Comment: It isn't possible for a differentiable function on $\Bbb{R}$ to have a local (much less global) minimum that isn't a stationary point. Unless I'm missing something, this means there are no $f$ that satisfy the given premises.

Comment: No, flat at $x$ means that all the derivatives (of all orders) vanish at $x$. So, being non-flat at a minimum means that  *some* derivative do not vanish. (so e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ satisfies my assumptions). The strict convexity around such a non-flat minimum follows from Taylor's expansion, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19473/104576

Comment: I'm still a little confused. You only assumed the function to be $C^1$. Does a function that's flat at $0$ need to be infinitely differentiable $0$? Or would it be enough for every derivative that exists to be $0$ (e.g. would $x|x|$ be considered flat at $0$)?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Then you may assume that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and with some non-zero derivative at $x=0$, or that it's $C^1$ and strictly convex in some neighbourhood of zero. I have edited the question to be more clear. Thanks for asking me for clarifications.

Comment: I gave an example of $x^4 + bx^3 + cx^2$. If someone are interested in it, please check my answer (true or wrong).

Comment: @River Li. Thank you for this example. It is very nice. I apologize for my late response. I wonder how did you think about that? this seems a bit magical to me...

Comment: @AsafShachar  You are welcome. I just tested some polynomials for $f(x)+f(2c-x) \ge 2 f(x)$ and found that quartic polynomial works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are counterexamples for each such $r,s$.

Before I start with the proof and deal with the technicalities, I'd like to present the basic idea: Take a convex function that fullfills all convexity conditions (here $x^2$), then pertube it a small bit on a short interval after $s$, such that it becomes concave there, but still keeps the monotonicity. This makes it not mid-convex arund $s$, while the pertubation is too small to affect the mid-convexity at $r$, which is "far away".

---

Define for $\delta > 0$

$$b_\delta(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2,                                   & \text {if } 0 \le x \le \frac{\delta}4;\\
\frac{\delta^2}8-(x-\frac{\delta}2)^2, & \text {if } \frac{\delta}4 \le x \le \frac{3\delta}4;\\
(x-\delta)^2,                          & \text {if } \frac{3\delta}4 \le x \le \delta;\\
0,                                     & \text {otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$
It's easy to see that this is a $C^1$ function, the parabolas have been "stuck together" such that their values and first derivates agree on the points where the piece-wise definitions change, we have
$$b_\delta(0)=b_\delta(\delta)=0, b_\delta(\frac{\delta}4)=b_\delta(\frac{3\delta}4)=\frac{\delta^2}{16}.$$

We also have
$$b'_\delta(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x,                                   & \text {if } 0 \le x \le \frac{\delta}4;\\
-2(x-\frac{\delta}2), & \text {if } \frac{\delta}4 \le x \le \frac{3\delta}4;\\
2(x-\delta),                          & \text {if } \frac{3\delta}4 \le x \le \delta;\\
0,                                     & \text {otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

and again we see that

$$b'_\delta(0)=b'_\delta(\delta)=0, b_\delta(\frac{\delta}4)=\frac\delta2, b_\delta(\frac{3\delta}4)=-\frac\delta2$$

by using definitions on both sides of the piece-wise definition.

Since $b'_\delta$ is a piece-wise linear function, the minimum value is easily seen to be taken at $\frac{3\delta}4$, so we get

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R: b'_\delta(x) \ge -\frac\delta2.$$

We now define a counterexample to the proposition, as

$$f_\delta(x):=x^2-4b_\delta(x-s)$$

First we see that $f_\delta(x)=x^2$ outside $[s,s+\delta]$, so the conditions on monotony of $f$ are fullfilled outside $[s,s+\delta]$.

Inside this interval, we have

$$f'_\delta (x)=2x-4b'_\delta(x-s) \le 2(s+\delta) + 4\frac\delta2 = 2s+4\delta,$$

where we used $2x \le 2(s+\delta)$ for $x\in [s,s+\delta]$ and the lower bound for $b'_\delta$ given above.

That means for $\delta$ small enough ($\delta < -\frac{s}2$) we also have $f'_\delta (x) < 0$ in the interval $[s,s+\delta]$ and since with the above upper bound $s+\delta < 0$ that is exactly what is needed to prove that our $f_\delta$ has the correct monoticity. In addition since $f_\delta(x)=x^2$ around $x=0$, it is strictly convex there.

I'll show that $f$ is not midpoint-convex at $s$ for any $\delta$.

We have $f_\delta(s)=s^2, f_\delta(s-\frac\delta4) = (s-\frac\delta4)^2, f_\delta(s+\frac\delta4) = (s+\frac\delta4)^2-4b_\delta(\frac\delta4) = (s+\frac\delta4)^2 -4 \frac{\delta^2}{16}$

and so $2f_\delta(s) = 2s^2$, but

$$f_\delta(s-\frac\delta4) + f_\delta(s+\frac\delta4) = (s-\frac\delta4)^2 + (s+\frac\delta4)^2 -4 \frac{\delta^2}{16} = 2s^2 +2\frac{\delta^2}{16} - 4 \frac{\delta^2}{16} = 2s^2 -2\frac{\delta^2}{16} < 2f_\delta(s)$$

in contradiction to midpoint-convexity at $s$.

Now the only thing left to do is to prove midpoint convexity at $r$. That can only be broken if one of $x,y$ lies in the interval $[s,s+\delta]$, as otherwiese $f_\delta(x)=x^2$ which is convex everywhere and thus midpoint convex at any point.

So let's assume $x=r-\alpha$, $y=r+\alpha \in [s,s+\delta]$, we get similar to the above calculation $2f_\delta(r)=2r^2$ and

$$f_\delta(r-\alpha) + f_\delta(r+\alpha) = (r-\alpha)^2 + (r+\alpha^2) - 4b_\delta(r+\alpha-s) = 2r^2 + 2\alpha^2 - 4b_\delta(r+\alpha-s).$$

We have $r+\alpha \ge s \Rightarrow \alpha \ge s-r > 0$, so finally we get

$$f_\delta(r-\alpha) + f_\delta(r+\alpha) \ge 2r^2 + 2(s-r)^2 - 4b_\delta(r+\alpha-s)$$

But since $b_\delta(x) $ can be made as small as desired by decreasing $\delta$, we can find a suitable $\delta$ such that $2(s-r)^2 - 4b_\delta(x) >0$ for any $x$. That proves finally that the defined $f_\delta$ is a counteraxample for a sufficiently small $\delta$.

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing answer, thank you very much. I am really impressed by how you managed to go all the way from a vague geometric idea, into a full blown, complete and entirely rigorous solution. I don't think that this way is trivial. I really appreciate your careful handling of all the details, and the fact that you have bothered to write such a clear geometric "prologue" that conveys the intuition you had.

Comment: The point of the prologue was to make you understand where the idea comes from. The remaining part is "technique", where you need to combine things you know (like how to cobble together a $C^1$-function from 'simple' quadratic parabolas to make $b_\delta$) and then I just had to checks that the conditions are still satisfied (monotonocity, but no longer midpoint convex). But if you deal with real analysis it should be "clear" that the $b_\delta$ can be made $C^\infty$, with the help of functions from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: @AsafShachar Thanks for the bounty, but it wouldn't have been necessarry.

Answer (score 1):

*Problem*: Let $r < s < 0$ be given. Find a $C^\infty$ function $f : \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$ with $f(0)=0$ such that:
i) $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$;
ii) $f(x) + f(2r - x) \ge 2f(r)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$;
iii) $f(y) + f(2s - y) < 2f(s)$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}$;
iv) $f$ is strictly convex in some neighbourhood of $0$.

*Solution*: Let $f(x) = x^4 + bx^3 + cx^2$. Clearly $f(0)=0$.
We claim that $f$ satisfies i), ii), iii) and iv) if
\begin{align}
32c - 9b^2 &> 0, \tag{1}\\
6r^2 + 3br + c &> 0, \tag{2}\\
6s^2 + 3bs + c &< 0. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Indeed, first, we have $f'(x) = x(4x^2 + 3bx+2c)$, and if $32c - 9b^2 > 0$,
then $4x^2 + 3bx+2c > 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so i) is satisfied;
second, we have $f(x) + f(2r-x) - 2f(r) = 2(x-r)^2((x-r)^2 + 6r^2 + 3br + c)$,
and if $6r^2 + 3br + c > 0$, then ii) is satisfied;
third, we have $f(y) + f(2s-y) - 2f(s) = 2(y-s)^2((y-s)^2 + 6s^2 + 3bs + c)$,
and if $6s^2 + 3bs + c < 0$, then iii) is satisfied.
fourth, we have $f''(x) = 12x^2 + 6bx + 2c$, and if $c > 0$ (follows from $32c - 9b^2 > 0$),
then $f''(0) = 2c > 0$ and $f$ is strictly convex in some neighbourhood of $0$ (due to continuity of $f''(x)$).

Then, we prove that there exist $b, c$ such that (1), (2) and (3) are satisfied.
We simply choose $b = -3s$ and
$$c = 3s^2 - \frac{1}{2}\min\left(3(2r-s)(r-s), \ \frac{15}{32}s^2\right).$$
Indeed, first, since $c \ge 3s^2 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{15}{32}s^2$,
we have $32c - 9b^2 = \frac{15}{2}s^2 > 0$;
second,
since $c \ge 3s^2 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 3(2r-s)(r-s)$, we have
$6r^2 + 3br + c \ge \frac{3}{2}(2r-s)(r-s) > 0$;
third, since $c < 3s^2$,
we have $6s^2 + 3bs + c < 6s^2 + 3(-3s)s + 3s^2 = 0$.